# How to check in Javascript whether variables are null or not? And how to make a message pop up when the variables are null?

Tags: javascript

I need to solve these two issues.

Here's the code:

```js
function check() {
  var Name=document.getElementById("Name");
  var Surname=document.getElementById("Surname");
  if (Name==null && Name="" || Surname==null && Surname="") {
    alert("Enter the name or surname");
    return false;
  }
  return true;  
}
```

Basically, what this part should do is that:

- It should fetch the value of "Name" and "Surname" variables
- It should check whether the value of those two variables are null or not
- If the value is indeed null, then a message stating "Enter the name or surname" should pop up and notify the user to enter his/her name/surname.

Comment: What is `Name=""` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the values, you should do:

```
var Name=document.getElementById("Name").value;
var Surname=document.getElementById("Surname").value;
```

And to check if the user entered both:

```
if (Name==null || Name=="" || Surname==null || Surname=="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the nullchecking using `typeof`, the returning dom-element is also an object so `== ""` is not going to work.

```
function check(){
   var Name=document.getElementById("Name");
   var Cogn=document.getElementById("Surname");
   if (typeof Name === null || typeof Surname === null )
   {
    alert("Enter the name or surname");
    return false;
   }
   return true;  
}
```

Comment: `typeof var` returns a string value, therefore `typeof null` is `'object'` and to ensure it is really `null` the right check is triple equal `null === null // is true`.

Answer (score -2):

Use a triple equal to check not only a value but also its type.

```js
if (Name===null || Surname===null) {
```

In case of falsy values simply use `if (!Name || !Surname)`, then it checks for nulls, empty strings, false and undefined.

A single equal is assignation, `if (Name==null && Name="")` - sets Name to an empty string, not sure if it's a desired flow.

if `Name` and `Surname` are html `input` tags, then their value is of a string type and is under `.value` property.

In this case the code should looks like

```js
var Name=document.getElementById("Name").value.trim(); // avoid spaces
var Surname=document.getElementById("Surname").value.trim(); // avoid spaces
if (Name==="" || Surname==="")
{
  alert("Enter the name or surname");
  return false;
}
return true;
```